# Doctrine DQL - Logic check in select

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I am trying to use a LIKE comparison in a doctrine DQL in a MySQL database.
It works directly in SQL in the database and looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *, (name LIKE '%testO%') as partOfName
from organization
ORDER BY partOfName DESC;
```

This works just fine.

Now I try to implement this logic in Doctrine. My Querybuilder looks like this:

```php
oQueryBuilder
  ->from(OrganizationEntity::class, organization)
  ->select('organization')
  ->addSelect('(organization.name LIKE %:searchTerm%) AS searchTermIsPartOfName')
  ->setParameter('searchTerm', $sSearchTerm)
  ->orderBy('searchTermIsPartOfName', 'DESC')
;
```

Trying to run it or get the SQL out of it gives me the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 97: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'LIKE'

It is definitely the part about the LIKE. I commented the last three lines out and it works.

How do I translate the above working SQL into Doctrine DQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` expressions are covered under [**Conditional Expressions**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#conditional-expressions) in DQL's grammar. And unfortunately, it's not possible to use these directly within a `SelectExpression`.

However you can use them within a `CaseExpression`, which **can** be used in a `SelectExpression`, and replicate the same behaviour:

```
->addSelect('CASE WHEN (organization.name LIKE :searchTerm) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS searchTermIsPartOfName')
->setParameter('searchTerm', "%{$sSearchTerm}%")
```

(there was also a minor issue about your `LIKE` expression - I'm pretty sure the `%` signs need to be part of the parameter value, not the query itself)

Comment: That was it, great, thanks. Will give you the best answer as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot `''` after LIKE, replace with string

```
->addSelect('(organization.name LIKE %:searchTerm%) AS searchTermIsPartOfName')
```

on

```
->addSelect('(organization.name LIKE \'%:searchTerm%\') AS searchTermIsPartOfName')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thas didn't work either. @iainn explains why in his answer.